# How to enable the sidebar button in the help section of my Mac Os X Cocoa App?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have noticed that if you open the standard help of an Apple application like Notes, you will get an enabled sidebar button in the Apple Help Viewer, with expected functionality. I have not succeeded in making it enable in the help of my application.

[image: Notes standard help with sidebar opened]

Has anybody a solution for making it enable and use it in a non apple App ?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27171257/table-of-contentsside-bar-for-cocoa-apps-help-book/39932819